# (extjs) Get selected value of radio button in form. Not returning the value

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs4

I've followed the basic procedures for obtaining the selected value of my radio button form.

```
        ....
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        name: 'timespan',
        id: 'timespan',
        value: 7,
        checked: true,
        fieldLabel: 'Time Span',
        boxLabel: '7 days'
    }, {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        name: 'timespan',
        value: '30',
        fieldLabel: '',
        labelSeparator: '',
        hideEmptyLabel: false,
        boxLabel: '30 days'
    }, {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        name: 'timespan',
        value: '60',
        fieldLabel: '',
        labelSeparator: '',
        hideEmptyLabel: false,
        boxLabel: '60 days'
    }, {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        name: 'timespan',
        value: 'all',
        fieldLabel: '',
        labelSeparator: '',
        hideEmptyLabel: false,
        boxLabel: 'All' ....
```

I've used methods like:

```
Ext.getCmp('filter_form').getForm().getValues()['timespan']
```

But when I run this to the console, instead of getting the value of the selected button, I get the word `on`.  What gives?! I've tried several different combos of getValues, getForm, etc, but I always end up with `on` or `true` or `false`.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out! Turns out that my extjs sample code has an error!

I changed `value` to `inputValue`.  Taken from the Sencha Docs, `inputValue` is:

> The value that should go into the generated input element's value
>   attribute
>       and should be used as the parameter value when submitting as part of a form.
>       Defaults to: 'on'

Aha!! Because I hadn't specified a "real" value, it defaulted to `on`.

Be careful when using the extjs examples/sample code!

Answer (score 5):

try setting `inputValue` property of radio. Which is the value that should go into the generated input element's value attribute and should be used as the parameter value when submitting as part of a form.

```
{
        xtype          : 'radiofield',
        name           : 'timespan',
        inputValue     : '30',
        hideEmptyLabel : false,
        boxLabel       : '30 days'
}
```

then it can be accessed as

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=timespan]')[0].getGroupValue();
```

refer [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Radio-cfg-inputValue) [getGroupValue](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Radio-method-getGroupValue)

Comment: getGroupValue() wasn't reading for me. It wasn't recognized. I've found a 'workaround' however without using getGroupValue(). Thanks!